# Azure DevOps Nuget artifact feed ignoring last digit of the package version number if it is zero

Tags: azure-devops

I have a NuGet package with version 7.0.0.0. When I publish this package to Azure DevOps Nuget artifact feed, it is getting published/stored as 7.0.0
This is only happening with packages whose version numbers are ending with '0'. Other packages whose version number is say for example: 8.1.2.3, they are getting published properly.

Any idea why it is happening? I am publishing packages from Teamcity build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Nuget artifact feed ignoring last digit of the package version number if it is zero

This is an **expected** behavior.

With `NuGet 4.3.0+` and Visual Studio 2017 version `15.3+`, NuGet supports [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html):

> A specific version number is in the form `Major.Minor.Patch[-Suffix]`,
> where the components have the following meanings:
>
> - Major: Breaking changes
> - Minor: New features, but backwards compatible
> - Patch: Backwards compatible bug fixes only
> - -Suffix (optional): a hyphen followed by a string denoting a pre-release version (following the Semantic Versioning or SemVer 1.0
>   convention).

And there is a [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#normalized-version-numbers) for **NuGet 3.4 and later**:

**A zero in the fourth part of the version number will be omitted**

```
  1.0.0.0 is treated as 1.0.0
  1.0.01.0 is treated as 1.0.1
```

You could check the nuget official document [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#semantic-versioning-200) for some more details.