# Nuget pack using versioningScheme ='byEnvVar' not working

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline job with 2 tasks in it

Task 1 (Powershell@2): I am updating the build number to say "1.0.0.0" using command

$version = "1.0.0.0"

Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$version"

I can see that build version gets updated for this pipeline run.

Task 2 (NuGetCommand@2): I am using pack command to create the nuget package

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: Nuget Pack
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/${{parameters.packageid}}.nuspec'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: BUILD_BUILDVERSION
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

In task2, it is giving error "**##[error]No value was found for the provided environment variable.**"

I have tried
versionEnvVar: Build.BuildVersion as well but it simply does not work.

Here is the documentation link from MS
[NugetCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please check your env variables just before your nuget step by running this step: `- bash: env | sort`

Answer (score 0):

> Nuget pack using versioningScheme ='byEnvVar' not working

As your description, you need using `Build.BuildNumber` instead of `BUILD_BUILDVERSION`, like:

```
versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
versionEnvVar: Build.BuildNumber
```

Besides, if you want use the `BuildNumber` as the package version, you could using the:

`versioningScheme: byBuildNumber`

Comment: Hi Leo, Thanks for your reply. I can't use byBuildNumber because my package version is 1.0.0.0 and when I pack this package it's version change to 1.0.0. I want to pack/publish package with all four digits in it's version '1.0.0.0'

Comment: @ViBi, you could not generate the package with version `1.0.0.0`. That because NuGet supports Semantic Versioning 2.0.0, you could check my another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814869/azure-devops-nuget-artifact-feed-ignoring-last-digit-of-the-package-version-numb/64816639#64816639. You could change it to `1.0.0.1`

Comment: Hi Leo, as per MS documentation "If you want to use the build number as is, you can use byEnvVar as described above, and set versionEnvVar to BUILD_BUILDNUMBER." It is quite confusing. My takeaway from the above statement is "If my build number is 1.0.0.0 then using byEnvVar, nuget package packing will use version 1.0.0.0"

Comment: When using `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task, you can use 
`versionEnvVar: 'Build.BuildNumber'`